# Did I calculate the size of this group right?

Tags: combinatorics

given the group $$\Omega = \{\left((P_1,F_1),...,(P_n,F_n)\right) \ : \ \forall \ j \ , \ P_j \in \{\mathsf{right},\mathsf{left},\mathsf{center}\} \ , \ F_j \in \{\mathsf{eng},\mathsf{sci}\}\}$$

I calculated that $$|\Omega|=  6^n$$

this is because for every pair there is 6 options and than I multiple all the $n$ pairs and getting $$6^n$$ options.

if this is true, why do I multiple the pairs and not summing them up? what is the intuition behind that?

Comment: Try writing out the elements for $n=2$. That ought to sharpen your intuition.

Answer (score 1):

$6^n$ is correct.

Consider $n = 1$. The elements of $\Omega_1$ are:

- (right, eng)
- (left, eng)
- (center, eng)
- (right, sci)
- (left, sci)
- (center, sci)

There are six of them.

Consider $n = 2$. The elements of $\Omega_2$ are:

- $((\mbox{right}, \mbox{eng}), \omega)$

  - ((right, eng), (right, eng))
  - ((right, eng), (left, eng))
  - ...
  - ((right, eng), (center, sci))
- $((\mbox{left}, \mbox{eng}), \omega)$

  - ((left, eng), (right, eng))
  - ((left, eng), (left, eng))
  - ...
  - ((left, eng), (center, sci))
- ...
- $((\mbox{center}, \mbox{sci}), \omega)$

  - ((center, sci), (right, eng))
  - ((center, sci), (left, eng))
  - ...
  - ((center, sci), (center, sci))

That is to say, $\Omega_2 = \left( \Omega_1 \right)^2$.

We have six choices for the first pair, and for each of these, we have six choices for the second pair.

In general, $\Omega_{n} = \left( \Omega_1 \right)^{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication occurs when you are trying to find the cardinality of a Cartesian product or a special subset of a Cartesian product. Addition occurs when there is casework, meaning you are working with the partition of a set. In your case, there is enough flexibility that each pair is counting a $3\times 2$ size Cartesian product and the tuple of pairs is counting a $$\underbrace{6\times 6\times \cdots \times 6}_{n \text{ copies}}$$ Cartesian product.